# BadImageFormatException C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**BadImageFormatException : Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'PackagePattern, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ou une de ses dépendances. Tentative de chargement d’un programme de format incorrect.**

I got this error in my project and I didn't understand it. 
Any help, please?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by checking the processor type you are building for.  Assuming PackagePattern is your library, double-check that you haven't ended up with a x86 application relying on a x64 library (or vice versa).  If possible, you could start by setting PackagePattern to build for AnyCPU and see if the problem goes away.